# Gallery Disappears in Mobile View

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with some css and html and came across this website... Why when the window shrinks the gallery disappears? I've checked the source code and can't see any css (media queries) that suggest that sizing may be an issue?

Help a curious cat out

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="shoppable-instagram" style="clear:both" class="ps-container hide-for-small-only">
```

Remove class .hide-for-small-only from div id 'shoppable-instagram' and it will work fine.

Your New DIV should be:

```
<div id="shoppable-instagram" style="clear:both" class="ps-container">
```

This code is the reason for hiding that div into mobile devices. It's in foundation-flex.min.css line number 2

```
@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em)
    .hide-for-small-only {
        display: none!important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The site uses foundation, a framework which allows for faster and more efficient coding of websites. Foundation uses css classes to hide and display content based on the screen size. This is popular and easy outside of CMS as well. Basically you have an element like:

```
<div class="hide">
  // content
</div>
```

And you target that class through media queries to hide it at a specific break point:

```
.hide {
   display:block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    .hide{
       display:none;
    }
}
```

The same can be done in reverse to hide content initially and then show it for smaller screens. Foundation uses these class and break points to hide and show content for extra large, large, medium, and small screen.